# Does Angular 2 or Angular 2 CLI have (or plan to have) an addon system similar to Ember CLI's?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm not sure if it's specified or obscurely mentioned in any docs somewhere, but does Angular 2 or Angular 2 CLI have or plan to have an addon system similar to that of Ember CLI?

I'm curious about the idea of shareable Angular 2 components, Angular 1/2 directives, services, etc. that can be imported into your Angular 2 app.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out lately too.  There is this work in progress: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
But I can't seem to get it installed using npm--I might post it as an issue..

Comment: Yes, the plan is to support add-ons and external libraries. It will take some time to design and implement but it will be there.